# Center text output from a loop

Tags: c#

I'm working on a temperature converter, at the end the program has to put out Fahrenheit to Celsius or vice versa in an arranged way, like the image here

[image: Example]

meaning the C, F and = have to be aligned on each row, I tried string.Format but it only gives me errors.

```
 for (Farenheit = 0; Farenheit <= maxFarenheit; Farenheit = Farenheit + 5)
        {
            Celsius = 5 / 9.0 * (Farenheit - 32);
            Celsius = Math.Round(Celsius, 2);
            Console.WriteLine(Farenheit + " F = " + Celsius + " C");
        }
```

This the loop

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? String Format documentation is not intuitive in my opinion but, here it is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-6.0#control-spacing.

Comment: You can also use [String.PadRight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padright?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Note that you've spelled Fahrenheit incorrectly. I updated the text but not your code, as it is immaterial to the problem at hand. Just thought you'd like to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want

```text
  0.00 C =  32.00 F
  4.00 C =  39.20 F
  8.00 C =  46.40 F
 12.00 C =  53.60 F
 16.00 C =  60.80 F
 20.00 C =  68.00 F
 24.00 C =  75.20 F
 28.00 C =  82.40 F
 32.00 C =  89.60 F
 36.00 C =  96.80 F
 40.00 C = 104.00 F
 44.00 C = 111.20 F
 48.00 C = 118.40 F
```

The use format specifies a column width inside an interpolated string. This is done with `$"{value,width:format}"`. See the example code below:

Since this is C# and object-oriented in makes sense to create a class to handle the math.

```
public class Temperature
{
    public float Celsius { get; set; }
    public float Fahrenheit 
    {
        get
        {
            return 32f + (9f * Celsius) / 5f;
        }
        set
        {
            Celsius = 5f * (value - 32F) / 9F;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Temperature temperature = new Temperature();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            temperature.Celsius = 4f * i;

            Console.WriteLine($"{temperature.Celsius,6:F2} C = {temperature.Fahrenheit,6:F2} F");
        }
    }
}
```

Here the value of `6` designates the total width the value will occupy (6 spaces) and is justified by default. To make the value be left justified use a negative value, like `-6`.

Also, the specifier `F2` means to show two decimal places to the right of the point. For floating point values, use specifiers like `g4` for general formatting, `f4` for fixed # decimals, and `e4` for scientific notation.

An improvement can be made to include the string formatting inside the class, as in the code below with identical results.

```
public class Temperature
{
    public float Celsius { get; set; }
    public float Farenheit
    {
        get
        {
            return 32f + (9f * Celsius) / 5f;
        }
        set
        {
            Celsius = 5f * (value - 32F) / 9F;
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Celsius,6:F2} C = {Fahrenheit,6:F2} F";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Temperature temperature = new Temperature();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            temperature.Celsius = 4f * i;

            Console.WriteLine(temperature);
        }
    }
}
```

The key here is to override the `ToString()` function that the system uses to convert an object to a string value. It is called automatically by the `Console.WriteLine()` function and the point is that all formatting can be handled internally from the class.

Comment: I added a few more details about the format specification inside interpolated strings.